# React native SplashScreen.h file not found

Tags: ios, react-native

Hi, I'm new to react native technology and i'm trying to create splash screen for iOS by using this steps in following link

[React Native Splash Screen (iOS)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0CC1UsvjDQ)

and i got this error as attached image

[SplashScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1nPP.png)

Please any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In react-native-splash-screen lib readme.md is not updated. So what you need to change is your AppDelegate.m & RNSplashScreen.m file. see the below code.

```
#import "SplashScreen.h" //replace this with #import "RNSplashScreen.h"
[SplashScreen show]; //replace this with [RNSplashScreen show];
```

In RNSplashScreen.m

```
//Replace this with below code
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(show) {   
    [SplashScreen show];
}

//Add this in place of above code.
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(show) {
[RNSplashScreen show];
}

//Add below path to search path.
//To fix 'RNSplashScreen.h' file not found, you have to select your project → //Build Settings → Search Paths → Header Search Paths to add:

$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/ios
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: i follow these steps in below link but the same error  https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Please see the edit.